# CSS - Multi-col submenu offset issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have created a menu dropdown, and a multi-col submenu. Please see the code at https://jsfiddle.net/fyrtpd7r/. If you hover over "Item A", it looks fine. But if you over item D, you can see the 2nd col in the submenu does not align with the top menu.

```
body{
    background-color:#ddd;
}
nav{
    background:#eee;
}
.menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.menu, ul.sub-menu, .col-menu{
    list-style:none;
}
ul.menu > li{ 
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
ul.sub-menu{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
ul.menu > li:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
ul.menu > li:hover ul.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}

/* multi col */ 
ul.multi-col{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
} 

ul.multi-col ul.col-menu{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* multi col - right align */ 
ul.multi-col.right-align{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
} 

ul.multi-col.right-align ul.col-menu{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

remove these styles from your css.
get rid of the class right-align

```
/* multi col - right align */ 
ul.multi-col.right-align{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
} 

ul.multi-col.right-align ul.col-menu{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```